# Compiling for iPhone simulator from command line, to tools are found

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, llvm

I am compiling an open source project (pjsip) from command line. When I do it for the device everything works fine and all the needed tools, compilers etc are found in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin

However I would expect the same folder structure to be available for the simulator as well but it is not. I have no bin folder in:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr

so the compiler etc are not found.

I have installed both iOS5.0 and 6.0 simulators as well as the command line tools. Are there specific command line tools for the simulator or what might I be missing?

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Nope.

You're fine - all the tools required to compile for the simulator should be available within the iPhoneOS folder.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will try to modify the configure script and try again. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: It now worked fine using the Developer path from the iPhoneOS folder instead. Thanks for the help.